# Twitter Rest API not accepting headers for tokens in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api, twitter, alamofire

I am trying to load a JSON page on the console and I keep getting the error message that I have bad authentication data.

I am using the correct headers that the Twitter Developer program gave me to access the JSON but it's not working. Am I doing something wrong with Alamofire? Do I have the wrong format for the headers? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: code]
[image: error]

Comment: You need an "Authorization" header key.  Have a read through https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests, where it states:   "At a very simplified level, Twitter’s implementation requires that requests needing authorization contain an additional HTTP Authorization header with enough information to answer the questions listed above. A version of the HTTP request shown above, modified to include this header, looks like this (normally the Authorization header would need to be on one line, but has been wrapped for legibility here):"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following in-line authorization header format with your values:

let headers = ["Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog, oauth_nonce=kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg, oauth_signature=tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D, oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1, oauth_timestamp=1318622958, oauth_token=370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb, oauth_version=1.0"]

Comment: The format you gave me worked however it's giving me a new error: code = 32; message = "Could not authenticate you."; Any ideas?